# writing in android with background color

Tags: android, textview, background-color

I'm new to android development and i'm trying to write something with background color which i set in the main.xml file/
My writing code is this

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(s);
setContentView(textView);
```

When I run the program the "setContentView" overwrite the background color, is there another way of writing which doesnt over write what written in the main.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have the TextView in your XML file and then reference your TextView like this

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_textview);
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be a simplier way (Perhaps theres an `android:background` attribute for a LinearLayout that you can change)

But the only thing I can think of now is, for your case, to subclass TextView and implement `onDraw` this way:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);
   canvas.clipRect(new Rect(0, 0, textViewWidth, textViewHeight), Region.Op.REPLACE);
   canvas.drawColor(yourBgColor);
}
```

I'm **sure** theres another way... but if you can't find any, you can use this :)